# Mapping url to a single controller with different method with Spring 3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have to map different url to single controller
e.g.

```
/test/read
/test1/read
/test2/read

/test/submit
/test1/submit
/test2/submit
```

So at the class level I use `@RequestMapping(values ={"/test/*", "/test1/*","/test2/*"})` and at method level `@RequestMapping(read)` and for other method `@RequestMapping("submit")`.

This fails and says that read is already mapped. 
By default I think RequestMappingHandlerMapping is being used.

How to do this kind of mapping please suggest.

Comment: I tried the same mappings with SpringBoot 1.2.3 and its working fine. Seems Spring 3 has some issue with it. Can you try using @RequestMapping(value ={"/test/", "/test1/","/test2/"}) at the class level?

Comment: Please add web.xml - this might be due to faulty DispatcherServlet config.

Comment: I tried doing that and it didn't worked. I think Spring 3 have some changes related to this which prevents it from mapping this way.

Comment: I just tried with Spring 3.2.2.RELEASE version and its working fine. What exact version you are using?

Comment: I understood the issue was not actually of mapping but two bean in application context. I have raised a query for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346645/applicationcontext-with-same-bean-having-requestmapping-fails?noredirect=1#comment48791131_30346645