# ApplicationContext with same bean having @RequestMapping fails

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my applicationContext.xml I have 2 beans with same class and different id(test and test1). The application context gets loaded correctly, but when I add `@RequestMapping` to one method then the bean creation fails with the below error. This used to work with `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` but its failing with `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`.

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'test1' bean method 
public java.lang.String com.test.render()
to {[/render],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'test' bean method
```

Please suggest how to fix this.

Code:

**applicationContext.xml**

```
 <bean id="test" class="com.abc.test" />

 <bean id="test1" class="com.abc.test" />
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
 @RequestMapping( value ={"/test/", "/test1/"})
public class test {

    @RequestMapping("render")
    public String render ()
    {
        //some code here.
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please attach applicationContext.xml  and  Controller code !!!
It will help to understand your problem..

Comment: as http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html says all attrbiutes of @RequestMapping are arrays, therefore they can take multiple values but ,you can not create two bin for same classes  so remove <bean id="test1" class="com.abc.test" /> should resolve your problem...

Comment: Actually I want to create beans in that way

Comment: can you explain why you want to create two beans of same class???

Comment: These beans have some properties which are set differently for each bean instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this...
switch from singleton approach to prototype and inside the xml do

While programmatically define

```
    class P1 {
       @Autowire
       NotSoSingleton prototypedBean;
    }

    class P2 {
       @Autowire
       NotSoSingleton prototypedBean;
    }

    class P3 {
       @Autowire
       NotSoSingleton prototypedBean;
    }
```

Would this approach do?

Comment: I didn't understand the solution completely. For now, I removed the @RequestMapping from the methods and  have created a custom RequestMappingHandlerMapping to have registered the method. This was done but the issue I am facing after this is that I have <mvc:annotation-driven> and I cant remove that, so my custom RequestMappingHandlerMapping is not getting being used the default one registered by <mvc:annotation-driven> is being used. Is there any work around it. So that even after having <mvc:annotation-driven> custom RequestMappingHandlerMapping can be used?

Comment: instead of declaring test and test1 do this:
assuming that you want to do like in my example (and the class is NotSoSingleton class) in the xml file add
<bean id="prototype" class="com.sample.NotSoSingleton " 
         scope="prototype"/>

Answer (score 0):

I could find a work around with this. This solution if for the comments I posted on 21-May

I used order property to instantiate the custom defined RequestMappingHandlerMapping in the xml file and it worked!!
It took my custom defined RequestMappingHandlerMapping instead of the default one loaded by `<annotation-driven>`.